# Google Maps with Dart: retain function is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dart

I have been following this tutorial to display a Google Map using Dart https://developers.google.com/live/shows/240588492-6002 however have come across a problem with the js.retain function.
This is my code so far:

```
 import 'dart:html';
 import 'package:js/js.dart' as js;
 import 'package:google_maps/google_maps.dart';

void main() {
  final mapOptions = new MapOptions()
  ..zoom = 8
  ..center = new LatLng(-34.397,150.644)
  ..mapTypeId = MapTypeId.ROADMAP;

final map = new Gmap(query("#map-canvas"),MapOptions);
js.retain(map);
```

I have followed the tutorial exactly up to 3:11 where he displays his map however my project has the error "the function 'retained' is not defined" as well as the warning that the Gmap class is undefined.

I have found little material online to help with this so any ideas or input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code snippet is out-dated. `retain` does not exist anymore.

Please use https://github.com/a14n/dart-google-maps/blob/master/example/01-basics/map-simple/page.dart :

```dart
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:google_maps/google_maps.dart';

void main() {
  visualRefresh = true;
  final mapOptions = new MapOptions()
    ..zoom = 8
    ..center = new LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
    ..mapTypeId = MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    ;
  final map = new GMap(querySelector("#map_canvas"), mapOptions);
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much that has solved the error. The project still breaks on exception however I think i haven't added the API key information correctly. I have obtained an API key, client ID and client secret but not sure how I apply them to this project?

Comment: You can try https://github.com/a14n/dart-google-maps/blob/master/example/01-basics/map-simple/map.html on _localhost_. You don't need an API key for that.

Comment: Don't forget to validate the answer.

Comment: Sorry that's it validated now. The project runs without any errors however nothing displays not too sure why at the moment. Thanks again for your help.